# Error "Uncaught PDOException", even though I use try-catch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm connecting to a mySQL database using PDO. When the login is wrong it gives a whole stacktrace of errors, even though I used try-catch.

```
try
{
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host='host' dbname='db' charset=utf8", $username, $password);        

    // Tried both with and without these attributes
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Database connection error: " . $e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
```

When this code is run - with a non-existing database name - I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044]
>   Access denied for user 'user' to database 'db' in .....

It prints out all the information. In case there's some error in the login, I just want the code to exit and write a message to a log file.

Why does the *catch* not catch this exception?

I'm using a local Apache server on my Windows computer. Maybe this is caused by some mis-configuration?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this code in a namespace? Perhaps try adding a backslack in front of PDOException (`\PDOException`) to tell it to use the root namespace? If you don't do this it'll search your current namespace (eg. `KMK\apps\PDOException`)

Comment: this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890813/pdoexception-not-being-caught

Comment: Thank you @h2ooooooo. The code was in a namespace. If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're running the code in a namespace.

Take the following code:

```
<?php

namespace foo\bar;

// This PDOException has the full class name \foo\bar\PDOException 
// because it's created in a namespace
class PDOException extends \Exception {} // Just so PHP won't throw an error

$exception1 = new PDOException('foo'); // Referencing the local namespace (foo\bar)
$exception2 = new \PDOException('foo'); // Referencing the global namespace
//                ^ -- The backslash means we are refering to the global namespace

var_dump(get_class($exception1)); // string(20) "foo\bar\PDOException" - local scope
var_dump(get_class($exception2)); // string(12) "PDOException" - global scope
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/843256)

As you can see if we are *inside* of a namespace and don't prepend our global classes with a backslash, it'll automatically assume that the class you're referencing is a a child class under the same namespace.

**Solution**:

Therefore you need to use `\PDOException` rather than `PDOException`. That way it knows to look in the *global* scope of classes rather than in your current namespace.